# Split a wav file into multiple overlapping .wav files using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I need to split big .wav files into small chunks of the same interval.
This can be done using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -f segment -segment_time 59 -c copy parts/out%09d.wav
```

but the requirement is some overlap. I am using these chunks for transcription and overlap will help in joining the chunked transcription results. Is there a way to get the overlapped audio chunks?

Comment: Segment muxer doesn't accept overlapping ranges; sorry.